# Laravel Blade not working with Sentry method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, cartalyst-sentry

I'm trying to write a .blade.php view that does:

- Show the user profile information
- If the user is banned, show a message "User is banned." instead.
- If you're logged in as an ADMIN (that is, if you have the permission 'admin'), instead of showing that message, show the user profile with an extra information saying the user is banned.

  Here is my view:

  ```
  @extends ('layout.main')

  @section('content')

  @if(! $throttle->banned==1)
          {{ $user->username }} <br>
          {{ $user->summoner_name }}<br><br>
          {{ $user->bio }}<br>
          {{ $user->punishments }}<br>
  @else
          {{ "This user is banned." }}
                  @if(Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('admin'))
                          {{ $user->username }} <br>
                          {{ $user->summoner_name }}<br><br>
                          {{ $user->bio }}<br>
                          {{ $user->punishments }}<br>
                          {{ ($throttle->banned == 1) ? "User is banned." : '' }}<br>
                          {{ $throttle->getSuspensionTime() }}<br>
                   @endif
  @endif

  @stop
  ```

And my controller:

```
<?php

class ProfileController extends BaseController {

        public function main($username) {

                try {
                        $throttle = Sentry::findThrottlerByUserLogin($username);

                        $user = User::where('username','=',$username);

                        if($user->count()) {

                                $user = $user->first();
                                return View::make('profile.main')
                                        ->with('user',$user)
                                        ->with('throttle',$throttle);

                        } else {

                                return App::abort(404);
                        }
                }
                 catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
                 {
                        echo 'User not found.';
                 }
        }

}
```

That said, I keep getting the error "Call to a member function hasAccess() on a non-object" on the debugger whenever I use

```
@if(Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('admin'))
```

The syntax looks OK to me, so I really don't get why Sentry does not recognize it as an object. What could it be? Is there a simple solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException` All that typing for one Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

@patricus, thanks for the help! That was not what I meant but it gave me the info I needed. When I called the method `Sentry::getUser()`, I was trying to get the user who was currently logged in and seeing the view, not the profile owner. But as you said, the method was returning NULL because I used it without checking if there was a logged in user to begin with!

So what actually fixed the issue was rewriting

`@if(Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('admin'))`

to

`@if(Sentry::check() && Sentry::getUser()->hasAccess('admin'))`

And thank you for the extra tips. I'm fairly new to Sentry, Laravel and PHP itself, so the code may get messy. All fixed and cleaned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Sentry::getUser()` will return `null` if the user is banned. Therefore, you're calling `hasAccess()` on a null object, giving you the error you're seeing.

I'm assuming your `User` model is extending the `Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\Eloquent\User` model, so I believe you could just use `$user->hasAccess('admin')` in your view.

A couple other notes:

I think you could probably shorten your Controller to something like this:

```
try {
    // throws Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException if user not found
    $throttle = Sentry::findThrottlerByUserLogin($username);

    // throws Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException if user not found
    $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin($username);

    return View::make('profile.main')
        ->with('user',$user)
        ->with('throttle',$throttle);
}
catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UserNotFoundException $e)
{
    return App::abort(404);
}
```

Also, you should use `$throttle->isBanned()` instead of checking `$throttle->banned == 1`.  Likewise for `$throttle->isSuspended()`, if you need it.